# HTML - How can I create an increment/decrement textbox on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can i create a increment/decrement *text box* in HTML Page using jquery or Javascript.... [image: The image are given below]

and also i want to set maximum and minimum values....

How to i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `increment/decrement text box or list box`?
Do you want to increment value in that box or do you want to increase/decrease number of such boxes?
And what do you mean by `list box`? Do you mean `select` element?

Comment: Hi @Maverick.. It's not `select` control.. i need a html textbox with 2 arrow img buttons... when click *up arrow* want to increment the integer value & when click *down arrow* want to decrement that integer value....

Comment: Oh! In that case `input type="number"` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes... But i am not using HTML5.. so `input type="number"` is not there in html...

Comment: Check the answer I posted a few mins back

Comment: answered here... [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43876534/525495)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here. I have also used it.

[numeric-up-down-input-jquery](http://www.misfitgeek.com/numeric-up-down-input-jquery/)

Comment: Hi @rahul... Thanks for your replay.... i need to use HTML controls only not ASPX controls..

Comment: hi @ManikandanSethuraju i have used this with html controls only you can use it simply with html control also

Comment: Yes @rahul..... i tried with html text box.. its working fine... But, one thing when i remove `$("#switcher").themeswitcher();` that up/down arrow image is not displaying...

Comment: Oops... when i changed the image path from CSS.. its working fine... Thank you very much for your answer...

Comment: 404 Page showing... Please give any trusted site link.

Answer (score 12):

Simple :)

HTML :

```
<div id="incdec">
    <input type="text" value="0" />
    <img src="up_arrow.jpeg" id="up" />
    <img src="down_arrow.jpeg" id="down" />
</div>
```

Javascript(jQuery) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#up").on('click',function(){
        $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())+1);
    });

    $("#down").on('click',function(){
        $("#incdec input").val(parseInt($("#incdec input").val())-1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi @Maverick... Thanks for your answer... i need a textbox like above image (in my question).. dont want to use any buttons....

Comment: Replace those buttons with images.

Comment: As Maverick has pointed out, you can achieve what's required using his code in combination with images and imaginative CSS. Place your textbox, increment image and decrement image inside a div. Remove the border from the textbox and instead apply the border to the div in the fashion of your desired textbox look. This will create the illusion that the increment and decrement images are inside the textbox when in actuality, the textbox and images are inside a div that simply looks like a textbox. This is a literal case of thinking outside of the box :-)

Comment: @Maverick: Based on the above code, I'd like to know how to stop decrementing at 0.

Comment: @Maverick: I launched a separate question and arrived at an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139247/jquery-stop-decrementing-textbox-value-if-value-equals-0

Comment: When clicking the decreasing button, it goes down two points every time. How to make it so it reduces only 1? Txs, @AdityaParab

Answer (score 9):

did you try `input type="number"`?

Comment: It may be worth adding a note that your answer is only relevant if the OP is targeting HTML5-capable browsers...

Comment: the question is 7 years old. I suppose this wasn't available at that time.

Answer (score 4):

Just try

```html
<input type="number" name="points" step="1">
```

that's it.
In the step, you can enter any value you want. And the arrows will move that many steps on clicking.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use jquery ui spinner . For a demo take a look at the link [here](http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html)

Comment: Hi @BP RAM... i tried with html text box.. its working fine... But, one thing when i remove $("#switcher").themeswitcher(); that up/down arrow image is not displaying...

Comment: Oops... when i changed the image path from CSS.. its working fine... Thank you very much for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try this Spinner Control. hope this will help you.

http://www.devcurry.com/2011/09/html-5-number-spinner-control.html

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (JQuery) of increment and decrement for both ( - and + )   ##

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#cost').w2form ({
name : 'cost',
style : '',
fields : [
          {
            name : 'amount',
            type : 'int'
          }
        ]
});
$("#amount").keydown(function (e) {
var key = e.keyCode;
if (key == 40) {
    if ( $(this).val() != "") {
        $(this).val();
    } else {
        $(this).val("0");
        w2ui['cost'].record[$(this).attr('name')] = "0";
        w2ui['cost'].refresh();
    }
}
});
}
```

### HTML

```
<html>
<form>
<label>Amount</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" style= "width: 140px"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function incerment(selector, maxvalue){
    var value = selector.val() != undefined ? parseInt(selector.val()) : 0;
    var max_value = maxvalue != undefined ? parseInt(maxvalue) : 100;
    if(value >= max_value){
     return false;
    } else {
     selector.val(++value);
    }
}
function decrement(selector, minvalue){
    var value = selector.val() != undefined ? parseInt(selector.val()) : 0;
    var min_value = minvalue != undefined ? parseInt(minvalue) : 1;
    if(value <= min_value){
        return false;
    } else {
        selector.val(--value);
    }
}

//MAXIMUM/MINIMUM QUANTITY
    $('#up').click(function(){
        incerment($("#incdec input"));
        return false;
    });
    $('#down').click(function(){
        decrement($("#incdec input"));
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Start of arrow keyup and keydown by JavaScript (JQuery)

```
$("#amount").on('keydown', function (event) {

    //up-arrow
    if (event.which == 38 || event.which == 104) {
        $(this).val((parseInt($(this).val()) + 1));

    //down-arrow
    } else if (event.which == 40 || event.which == 98) {
        $(this).val((parseInt($(this).val()) - 1));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript

```
function forKeyUp(value,e){
e = e || window.event;
 if (e.keyCode == '38' || e.keyCode == '104') {
if(parseInt(value)<1000){
value=(parseInt(value) + 1);
var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
$("#"+id).val(value);
}
}
else if (e.keyCode == '40' || e.keyCode == '98') {
if(parseInt(value)>0){
value=(parseInt(value) - 1);
var id = $(e.target).attr('id');
$("#"+id).val(value);
}
}}
```

//Call function

```
$("#amount")..on('keydown', function (event) {
forKeyUp($(this).val(),event);
});
```

Comment: please add some explanation