# jQuery: Stop decrementing textbox value if value equals 0

Tags: jquery, function, increment, decrement

## What I have:

I have a readonly textbox and two links. The first link increments the value of the textbox by 1 whereas the second link decrements the value by 1.

## What I need:

I need the textbox value to stop decrementing at zero (I don't want negative numbers).

## My code:

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(".increment").on('click',function(){
    jQuery(this).next(".amount input").val(parseInt(jQuery(this).next(".amount input").val())+1);
});

jQuery(".decrement").on('click',function(){
    jQuery(this).prev(".amount input").val(parseInt(jQuery(this).prev(".amount input").val())-1);
});
```

*Note: .next and .prev are used because I have multiple textboxes.*

**HTML:**

```
<!--This block of code is occurs more than once.-->
<td class="amount">
    <a href="#" class="increment"></a>
    <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="0" />
    <a href="#" class="decrement"></a>
</td>
```

## A loose guess:

...with regards to decrementing...

```
// open onclick code here

    if (jQuery(this).prev(".amount input").val != "0"){

        // decrement code here

    }

// close onclick code here
```

## Resources:

My working code is modelled on this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12209831/835950

...at which a fiddle exists for convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/iMaverick/S3PLG/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4pWXQ/)

```
$("#down").on('click',function(){
    var value = (parseInt($("#incdec input").val() , 10) - 1);
    $("#incdec input").val((value-1) < 0 ? 0 :(value -1));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This works readily when I integrate .next and .prev.

Comment: Specify a radix for `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks, i forget about that.. Its really imp.. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Almost:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $textbox = $("#incdec input");

    $("#up").click(function(){
        var value = parseInt($textbox.val(), 10);

        $textbox.val(value + 1);
    });

    $("#down").click(function(){
        var value = parseInt($textbox.val(), 10);

        if (value > 0) {
            $textbox.val(value - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML5 also includes an `<input type="number">` element:

```
<input type="number" min="0" value="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Though the condition structure matches what I was attempting, I cannot manage to implement your code when I integrate .next and .prev as outlined in the example in my question. I'm additionally unsure what the 10 following the comma represents. I considered the HTML5 solution initially but opted instead for a manual solution that allows me greater control over the design.

Comment: @DominorNovus: `10` is base 10. If you don't specify the base, `parseInt()` is free to choose whatever it wants. As for your problem, you will need to provide more context. What does your actual HTML look like?

Comment: That's understandable. I didn't emphasize why I'm using .next and .prev. I've edited my question to provide the requested context. Please refer to "My code:" section, specifically the note and mark-up. You can view the working code that I was able to derive from PSCoder's answer here: http://pastebin.com/WneuWRrn

Comment: @DominorNovus: Cramming so much code into one line is a bad idea.

Comment: Are you referring to my use of .next/.prev vs writing a separate function for each textbox or are you referring to PSCoder's solution?

Comment: What are the superior alternatives? 1) The use of .prev/.nav is difficult to circumvent considering I have hundreds (literal hundreds) of textboxes. Writing a function for each seems overkill unless you're suggesting a different remedy. 2) Regarding the condition for checking for zero, I'm happy to break the code out into more lines as per your example except I cannot manage to make it work with .next and .prev.

Comment: @DominorNovus :: seems like I arrived late to answer your question :)

Comment: @Maverick :: Not to worry, you provided me with the original basis for incrementing/decrementing the value of the textbox.