# Create Up and Down arrow icons or buttons using pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, arrow-keys

I am trying to create below shown "up and down" control buttons using pure CSS and no Background image.

[image]

But when I added the CSS for arrows in "`li.className:after` or `li.className:before` " the position of main boxes moved.

**Here is the Fiddle for the issue I am getting >** **http://jsfiddle.net/8usFk/**

Below is the Code for the same:

**HTML**

```
<div class="positionCameras">
    <ul>
        <li title="Move Up" class="cameraLeft" id="cameraUp"></li>
        <li title="Camera" class="cameraIcon"></li>
        <li title="Move Down" class="cameraRight" id="cameraDown"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.positionCameras ul, .positionCameras li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft, .positionCameras li.cameraIcon, .positionCameras li.cameraRight {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 15px #cccccc;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before {
    content:" ";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraIcon {
    cursor: default;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8.7px 5px 0 5px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest.

Comment: You might consider using some character codes for the arrows instead - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701192/ascii-character-for-up-down-triangle-arrow-to-display-in-html

Comment: A bit of a hack but setting `position: fixed; left: 21px; top: 21px;` in `.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before` would fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set pseudo to `display:inline-block` (or any other values but inline.) you can size it.

Then,

1. to center it: `text-align:center` on parent.
2. To `vertical-align` it : `line-height:20px` (25px -5px  wich is half of the height of pseudo element) and set : `vertical-align:middle` to pseudo element:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8usFk/20/)**

```
.positionCameras ul, .positionCameras li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;/* UPDATE*/
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft, .positionCameras li.cameraIcon, .positionCameras li.cameraRight {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 15px #cccccc;
    text-align:center;/* UPDATE*/
    line-height:20px;/* UPDATE*/
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;/* UPDATE*/
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    vertical-align:middle;/* UPDATE*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraIcon {
    cursor: default;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 8.7px 5px 0 5px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This option always centers the arrows regardless of size and does not require fixed Value margins

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/8usFk/17/)

**CSS**

```
.positionCameras ul, .positionCameras li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* added */

}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft, 
.positionCameras li.cameraIcon, 
.positionCameras li.cameraRight {
    position: relative; /* added */
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 15px #cccccc;
}

.positionCameras li.cameraIcon {
    cursor: default;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before,
.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before{
    content:""; 

    /* added for positioning magic */
    position: absolute; 
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);    
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
    /* end added */

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
}

.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before {
    border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}

.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before {
    border-width: 10px 5px 0 5px;
    border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
vertical-align:top;
```

to the CSS applied on the div.

ie. you CSS class should be as such:

```
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft, .positionCameras li.cameraIcon, .positionCameras li.cameraRight {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 15px #cccccc;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

That will work just fine.

You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhX87/

**UPDATE**

Add the following CSS for the image to center properly:

```
position:relative;
bottom:11px;
left:7px;
```

in the `.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before` class.

This should center the image as you want.

See this here: http://jsfiddle.net/rhX87/1/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks! I added "vertical-align:top;" to <li> tag, the boxes are all aligned now... but The Arrow is still at bottom

Comment: Add margin for the arrow. Let me try this and post the code.

Comment: See the updated section of the answer. This should solve the image centering issue as well!!

Answer (score 0):

## DEMO

**HTML**

```
<div class="positionCameras">
    <ul>
        <li title="Move Up" class="cameraLeft" id="cameraUp"></li>
        <li title="Camera" class="cameraIcon"></li>
        <li title="Move Down" class="cameraRight" id="cameraDown"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.positionCameras ul, .positionCameras li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft, 
.positionCameras li.cameraIcon, 
.positionCameras li.cameraRight {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #cccccc;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 15px #cccccc;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before,
.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before{
    padding:5px;
    color:#007bff;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:25px;
}
.positionCameras li.cameraLeft:before{
    content:"▼";
}
.positionCameras li.cameraRight:before{
    content:"▲";
}
.positionCameras li.cameraIcon:before{
    content:"•";
    padding:5px;
    color:#111;
    font-size:48px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Cool triangle characters! Any rendering issues across different browsers or locales?

Comment: @Peter The browsers handle them fine. You just need to ensure the font used to render them contains the characters. These are quite generic symbols and exist in most fonts. Microsoft recommend Segroe UI.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use `html character codes` and do this as in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7CXr/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my strictly html version.
You will need to add the javascript function "incrementMyNumber()" to handle the onclick events.
The key is the negative margin on the divs that contain the arrows.
You may need to play with the numbers, but this looks good in IE and Chrome.

```
<table>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="myNumber" style="width:50px" value="5" />
</td>
<td>
    <table style="border-spacing:0px;margin-left:-2px;width:20px;">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:1px solid black;height:8px;background-color:#dcdcdc;cursor:pointer" onclick="incrementMyNumber(1)">
                <div style="margin:-5px;font-size:8px;">&#x25B2;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black; height: 8px; background-color: #dcdcdc;cursor:pointer" onclick="incrementMyNumber(-1)">
                <div style="margin:-5px;font-size:8px;">&#x25BC;</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</td>
```